# express' response.sendFile() sends Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, react-router

I'm using [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md) with browserHistory. This function:

```
app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/index.html"))
})
```

is supposed to send the Index.html since the routing happens client-side with react-router. 
But somehow my index.html is misunderstood by the server and I get this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I don't know what the problem here is. Is the file path wrong? My tree looks like this:

```
/app
/app/myJavascriptStuff.js
/public
/public/index.html
/moreStuffThatsNotRelevant
/server.js <- my express file
```

without the above described function my page usually responds with:

Cannot GET /whatever

on every page refresh that doesn't happen on localhost:3000 (e.g. localhost:3000/whatever)

Because I'm aware that i suck at describing things, [here](https://github.com/Java-Jonas/problem-with-react-router) is a link to the repository.

Help is very appreciated. :)

Comment: What does your `index.html` look like?

Comment: I mentioned the [repository](https://github.com/Java-Jonas/problem-with-react-router) in the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you did not build your bundle.js file with your webpack. Before you can serve it you need to build it first.

Change you package.json script to

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --color --config  webpack.config.js --watch",
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
```

and run the command `npm run build` before running your server.

If you webpack bundle.js doesn't get created inside `/public/build` then create a directory `build` inside public and run the above command again.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot. this whole webpack thing still confuses me a bit too much :'D

Comment: No Problem , Glad to help :)

Answer (score 3):

Problem can be because for each request you are sending `index.html` even when browser asks for your `bundle.js` or `style.css` via

```
app.get('*', function (request, response){
  response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public/index.html"))
});
```

Define a `public` folder from where these files can be served let say public(where you have your `index.html` in your github repo). Let webpack to generate the `bundle.js` in that folder. Also point in your `index.html` to use `bundle.js` from that folder.

Next in your `server.js` you need to do some changes. Let `express` to use public path for serving these files when asked by browser.

An example can be -

```
const app             = express();
const publicPath     = express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), { redirect : false });

const indexPath  = path.join(__dirname, 'public/index.html');
app.use(publicPath);
app.get('/', function (_, res) { res.sendFile(indexPath) });
app.get('*', function (_, res) { res.sendFile(indexPath) });
```